# adding multiple query params in angular 14

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I am building a multi item filter for my app and I need to send multiple  queryparameters in API to get filtered items.

My question is that is there any other way than adding all the queryParams by hand since there are like 40-50 options to filter with. Can that somehow be done programmatically?

Pretty sure it would work if i manually made an object but im interested if there's a way to do it easier.

[image: link to filter]

Comment: Perhaps think this through - you have inputs, on an input change you have a collection of data that should be updated, then on submit you want that collection of data looped through and added as query params to a request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to programmatically generate query parameters.

You could maintain an array of param key/values using `Object.entries` to convert an object to an array of key/value pairs, and `Object.fromEntries` to convert from an array of key/value pairs back to an object.

```js
const params = { currency: 'USD', language: 'en-US' }
// convert to [['currency', 'USD], ['language', 'en-US']]
const arrayOfParams = Object.entries(params) 
// convert back to { currency: 'USD', language: 'en-US' }
const paramsObj = Object.fromEntries(arrayOfParams)
```

Then use `HttpParams` to serialize/deserialize an object to query params:

```js
import { HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http'
const paramsObj = { currency: 'USD', language: 'en-US'}
const params = new HttpParams({ fromObject: paramsObj })

/* Serializes the body to an encoded string, 
*  where key-value pairs (separated by =) are separated by &s. 
*/
const queryStr = params.toString()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object to keep track of all the filter option.

Then simply use `JSON.stringify` to convert it to JSON.

You could also ignore the `null` and `undefined` value by passing in a [replacer function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```js
let opt = {
    a: 'string',
    b: 5.1,
    c: true,
    d: { e: 'object' },
    f: ['array'],
    g: null,
    h: undefined,
  };
  
console.log(JSON.stringify(opt, (key, value) => {
    if (value !== null) return value;
}));
```